# How to customize dj-rest-auth Login serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, dj-rest-auth

I am using dj-rest-auth, django-allauth and djangorestframework-simplejwt.I want to customize dj-rest-auth Login serializer to include the following additional fields: (first_name, last_name, phone_number), validate them, authenticate them and login properly. Also i am using email instead of username as my main identifier.
This is my Custom User Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager

from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("An email has to be set")

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True.")
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUserModel(AbstractUser):
    username = None

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "phone_number",
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

This is my serializer.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, authenticate
from rest_framework import serializers, exceptions
from dj_rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer    
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import LoginSerializer
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from phonenumber_field.serializerfields import PhoneNumberField


class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        read_only_fields = [
            "id",
            "is_superuser",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "phone_number",
            "bio",
            "age",
            "date_joined",
        ]
        fields = [
            "id",
            "is_superuser",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "phone_number",
            "bio",
            "age",
            "date_joined",
        ]


class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = [
            "id",
            "is_superuser",
            "email",
            "password",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "phone_number",
            "date_joined",
            "last_login",
            "bio",
            "age",
        ]
        read_only_fields = [
            "is_superuser",
            "password",
        ]


class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    username = None
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = [
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "phone_number",
            "password",
        ]

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            "email": self.validated_data.get("email", ""),
            "first_name": self.validated_data.get("first_name", ""),
            "last_name": self.validated_data.get("last_name", ""),
            "phone_number": self.validated_data.get("phone_number", ""),
            "password1": self.validated_data.get("password1", ""),
            "password2": self.validated_data.get("password2", ""),
        }

    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        user.phone_number = self.cleaned_data.get("phone_number")
        user.save()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        return user


UserModel = get_user_model()


class CustomLoginSerializer(LoginSerializer):
    username = None
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()

    def authenticate(self, **options):
        return authenticate(self.context["request"], **options)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get("email")
        first_name = attrs.get("first_name")
        last_name = attrs.get("last_name")
        phone_number = attrs.get("phone_number")
        password = attrs.get("password")
        if email and first_name and last_name and phone_number and password:
            user = authenticate(
                email=email,
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                phone_number=phone_number,
                pasword=password,
            )
            if not user:
                msg = "Incorrect credentials."
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code="authorization")
        else:
            msg = "No email provided."
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        attrs["user"] = user
        return attrs
```

This is my views.py:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    from rest_framework import generics
    
from .serializers import UserListSerializer, UserDetailSerializer


class UserListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserListSerializer


class UserDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
```

I have all the settings setup correctly, so i have no problems there. My custom registration work fine too, eveything works fine. I just can't correctly override the Loginserializer. And for my endpoint url i am using dj-rest-auth 's default "dj-rest-auth/registration/" address.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you were able to find the right way to do it. I also had the same issue with LoginSerializer until I've added this to settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

This is my serializers.py

```
class AccountLoginSerializer(LoginSerializer):
username = None

def authenticate(self, **options):
    return authenticate(self.context["request"], **options)

def validate(self, attrs):
    email = attrs.get("email")
    ip_address = get_client_ip(self.context["request"])[0]
    password = attrs.get("password")
    if email and password:
        '''Check if IP address belongs to account with given email address'''
        try:
            if Account.objects.get(email=email).ip_address.filter(ip_address=ip_address).exists():
                user = authenticate(
                email=email,
                password=password,
                )
        
            else:
                msg = "IP address doesn't match. An email has been sent to verify this IP address."
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code="authorization")
            if not user:
                msg = "Invalid credentials."
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code="authorization")      
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            msg = "Invalid credentials."
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code="authorization")
    else:
        msg = "No email provided."
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
    attrs["user"] = user

    return attrs
```

Hope it helps someone with the same issue.